# Why am I getting this error while defining the types of the caught exceptions in the catch statement in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, types, syntax

I am playing around with dart syntax

And I was trying this code:

```
void main() {
  print("Hello to demo");

  try{
    throw Test("hello");
  }
  on Test catch(Test e, StackTrace s){ //error on this line 
    print("error message is ${(e).message}");
  }
}

class Test{

  String? message;

  Test(this.message);
}
```

The error message I get is

```
'catch' must be followed by '(identifier)' or '(identifier, identifier)'. 
 No types are needed, the first is given by 'on', the second is always 'StackTrace'
```

I know that dart is strongly typed language but the same time explicitly defining types is optional, but I don't know why am I getting this message here, are there some situations (like the `catch` here) where even specifying a type is forbidden and not even optional?

p.s.: I am reading the documentation [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#catch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `catch` is a keyword, not a function, and it is designed in a way that you can't set parameter types. You have to use it as [documented here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#catch), like:

```
try {
  // ···
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print('Exception details:\n $e');
} catch (e, s) {
  print('Exception details:\n $e');
  print('Stack trace:\n $s');
}
```

Your code works this way:

```
void main() { 
   print("Hello to demo");
   try { 
      throw Test("hello"); 
   } 
   on Test catch(e, s){ 
    print("error message is ${(e).message}");
    print("stacktrace is ${(s)}");
  }

} 
class Test {
   String? message; 
   Test(this.message);
}
```

Comment: So it is true that there are syntaxes in dart where you can't even specify the syntax (but it will be implicitly set)?

Comment: I guess so, like this `catch` is implemented. As I see Dart seeks practical ways, sets a lot of things implicitly: you don't have to use `new` to create an instance, there is  an implicit default constructor if you don't need arguments etc.

Comment: yeah idk, coming from java I like to define explicitlyy the types

Comment: @Haidar Mehsen The type in this case *is* explicit, it's just that the syntax for specifying that type is different than what you expect.